# In what scenario would I need 64bit php for large files or other uses?

Tags: php

As I understand it from answers to my other questions on SO, 64bit php is good when you have very large numbers, use files larger than 2GB, or need more than 4GB or memory.

My question is when would I need those things?  I want to use it for CRUD operations, a CMS, reports.  It is *possible* for me to have a missiion critical operation in the future.  I will be using a 64bit OS (Windows 2008 R2, Linux).

I'm not even sure what it means for php to use a "file larger than 2GB."

Comment: 64 bit PHP is probably a bad idea, since many tools/plugins that may be installed around it are only available in 32 bit. Mixing them may as well misbehave or even crash. I'd say, you need it when you cannot use 32 bits.

Comment: There's very little need in most PHP applications for 64-bit. Arguably dates, but if you use DateTime objects rather than the basic date functions then that isn't an issue as DateTime works 64-bit internally even on 32-bit PHP. Some scientific modelling applications perhaps, though you probably wouldn't write them in PHP in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to deal with **very** large numbers, you will probably need 64bit PHP.

- 32 bit PHP can handle integers in the range -2147483648 to 2147483647.
- 64 bit PHP can handle integers in the range -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807.

If you need to work with numbers larger than nine digits long, you probably need 64 bit build.

32 bit PHP will still work to some extent with large numbers; it will handle them as `float` or `string`. But you'll lose performance and precision, so it's not great.

The file size limit is unlikely to affect you. 2 gig is a very large size for a single file, since we're talking about a web-based system.

Comment: Consider the [2038 Problem](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FYear_2038_problem&ei=jRgFUreBBZHK9QSntoG4Cg&usg=AFQjCNEjeTBFYEb6e1NF74z1r64bU77c6Q&sig2=ZNU0eGZgbwzGkgyLdLCNZQ&bvm=bv.50500085,d.eWU) It's similar to the Y2K problem.

Comment: Though the 2038 problem can be eliminated by using DateTime objects